# ¿Cómo organizo el código de una función en google sheets de drive para que se ejecute solo en una hoja?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

tengo un problema con una macro de excel del drive la cual se ejecuta cada vez que se envia un formulario, al momento de grabarla lo hago en una sola hoja, pero al momento de ejecutarse me afecta la columna en todas las hoja, lo que ocasiona que se borren algunos datos

```
function MOLDE() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D134').activate();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D3:D134').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('D134'));
  spreadsheet.getRange('D134').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D3').activate();
};
```

este es el código, pero no se como limitarlo a que solo afecte la columna de la hoja en donde fue grabada

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. No es una macro de Excel, es un macro de Google Sheets. Son 2 programas y lenguajes diferentes

Comment: ok, muchas gracias

Comment: Podrias fijar la hoja: ```SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[numero de hoja donde ejecuta la macro]``

Comment: Muy buenas noches, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder , te pregunto, se coloca en la segunda linea o no, porque al colocarlo ya no hace ninguna función , por ejemplo le coloco hoja 1 y no funciona